# WP_Query posts by distance based on LAT & LNG in Database

Tags: wp-query, sort

I've got table in the WordPress database that has lat & lng stored and I'd like to add a sort feature on the results page 'Sort by Distance' that gets the locations that are closer to your provided lat & lng. I'm using WP_Query, it needs to work with it. Thanks :)

```
                $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'category__in' => $category,
                'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'age',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $age,
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'price',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $price,
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'group',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $group
                        )
                    ),
                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                ) );
```

Comment: Please provide more detail, including the code your are currently trying to use.

Comment: Just a basic WP_Query function. I have the lat & lng of the user & the lat & lng of the post stored in a variable. Editing the post with the current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the Haversine formula

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

This plugin might be of interest to you:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-geoposts/

> Provides WP_GeoQuery an extended WP_Query class for doing distance based and geo-aware queries.

it uses the Haversine formula here:

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-geoposts/trunk/query.php